# Scala Split Seq of Int from right when cumulative results meet the condition

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Have a sequence of positive integer, need to split the sequence from the right at the element when the sum till that element is less than or equal to a threshold. For example,

```
val seq = Seq(9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)
```

The threshold is 10, so the result is

```
Seq(9,8,7,6,5) and Seq(4,3,2,1)
```

I tried `dropWhile` and `scanLeft` after reverse, however, they are either quadratic or linear but complicated. Since our sequence may be very long, but normally the threshold is small and very few elements from the right side will meet the condition. I am wondering if there is any better and linear way to do it.

Comment: better than what? you should always present your approach beforehand

Answer (score 0):

This will stop as soon as the threshold is met. Unfortunately it uses a return to break.

```
val seq = Seq(9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)
val threshold = 10

def processList(): (Seq[Int], Int) = {
  seq.foldRight((Seq[Int](), 0)) {
    case (elem, (acc, total)) =>
      if (total + elem <= threshold) {
        (elem +: acc, total + elem)
      } else {
        return (acc, total)
      }
  }
}

processList()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's not a great way to do this with built-in methods, but you can implement it yourself:

```
  def splitRightCumulative[A, B](xs: Seq[A])(start: B)(f: (B, A) => B, cond: B => Boolean): (Seq[A], Seq[A]) = {
    def _loop(current: B, xs: Seq[A], acc: Seq[A]): (Seq[A], Seq[A]) = {
      val next = f(current, xs.head)
      if (cond(next)) {
        _loop(next, xs.tail, xs.head +: acc)
      } else {
       (xs.reverse, acc)
      }
    }
    _loop(start, xs.reverse, Seq.empty)
  }

  val xs = List(9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
  val (left, right) = splitRightCumulative(xs)(0)(_ + _, _ <= 10)
```

The second type parameter (`B`) might not be necessary if you're always accumulating the same type as what's in your collection.